# Suggest a proper location to save recorded voice notes

Tags: path, avaudiorecorder, temporary-directory, iphone-sdk-4.3

I am developing an iphone app with the capability of recording voice using AVAudioRecorder.Currently I am saving the notes in TemporaryDirectory()

```
recordedTmpFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Voice-%d.caf",count]]];
```

I am not sure weather this is the best location to store the file.
Can anyone suggest the best location to store such audio files which can be later accessed using there path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the same path and lowered the sample rate.I also made number of channels 1 from 2 which decreased the size of my voice record.